# Having the following error and can't figure it out

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Having the following error and can't figure it out.

```
model = sequential()
```

> NameError: name 'sequential' is not defined

Comment: You mean keras `Sequential` (with Capital letter)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably, you need to import the keras model as following,

```py
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential as sequential
```

Comment: You're welcome. In that case, you need to accept my answer as correct to close the issue.